# second div object wont open an popup window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have purchased some themes. And in that theme, there is a checkin/checkout section where user can choose datefrom dateto and number of guests.

The problem that I have is that I need two those sections with checkin/checkout and on the other **I cant get the popup window as I am getting on the first one**.
Problem is a unique identifier of the sub-section.

Here is the picture:[image: picture]

this is an HTML markup:

```html
<div class="container platinumcalendar">
    <div class="sc-hb-rooms-search style-01">
        <div class="hotel-booking-search style-01">
            <ul class="hb-form-table">
                <li><input type="text" id="inputPlatinumDate" class="multidate" value="" placeholder="Check-In" />
                </li>

                <li class="hb-form-field hb-form-check-in">
                    <div class="label">Check-In</div>
                    <div class="hb-form-field-input hb_input_field">
                        <input type="text" id="checkinday_platinum" class="day" value="" style="width: 68px;" />
                        <input id="checkinmonth_platinum" class="month" type="text" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="check_in_date_platinum" id="check_in_date1"
                            class="check-date hasDatepicker" value="" />
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="hb-form-field hb-form-check-out">
                    <div class="label">Check-Out</div>
                    <div class="hb-form-field-input hb_input_field">
                        <input type="text" id="checkoutday_platinum" class="day" value="" style="width: 83px;" />
                        <input id="checkoutmonth_platinum" class="month" type="text" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="check_out_date_platinum" id="check_out_date_platinum"
                            class="check-date hasDatepicker" value="" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="hb-form-field hb-form-number">
                    <div class="label">Number</div>
                    <div id="guests" class="hb-form-field-input hb_input_field">
                        <input type="text" id="number2" class="day" value="01" />
                        <input class="month" type="text" value="Guests" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="hb-form-field-list">
                        <div class="hb-form-field-input hb-guest-field">
                            <select name="adults_capacity" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
                                <option value="1">1</option>
                                <option value="2">2</option>
                                <option value="3">3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                            </select>
                            <span class="name">Guests</span>
                            <span class="number-icons goUp"><i class="ion-plus"></i></span>
                            <span class="number-icons goDown"><i class="ion-minus"></i></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="hb-submit">
                <span class="contact-info">Need Help: <span>(+381) xxxxxx</span></span>
                <button class="platinum_inquiry" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Send
                    Inquiry</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="empty-space"></div>
<div class="empty-space"></div>
<div class="empty-space"></div>
<div class="container goldcalendar">
    <div class="sc-hb-rooms-search style-01">
        <div class="hotel-booking-search style-01">

            <ul class="hb-form-table">
                <li><input type="text" id="inputGoldDate" class="multidate" value="" placeholder="Check-In" /></li>

                <li class="hb-form-field hb-form-check-in">
                    <div class="label">Check-In</div>
                    <div class="hb-form-field-input hb_input_field">
                        <input type="text" id="checkinday_gold" class="day" value="" style="width: 68px;" />
                        <input id="checkinmonth_gold" class="month" type="text" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="check_in_date_gold" id="check_in_date_gold"
                            class="check-date hasDatepicker" value="" />
                    </div>
                </li>

                <li class="hb-form-field hb-form-check-out">
                    <div class="label">Check-Out</div>
                    <div class="hb-form-field-input hb_input_field">
                        <input type="text" id="checkoutday_gold" class="day" value="" style="width: 83px;" />
                        <input id="checkoutmonth_gold" class="month" type="text" value="" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="check_out_date" id="check_out_date_gold"
                            class="check-date hasDatepicker" value="" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="hb-form-field hb-form-number">
                    <div class="label">Number</div>
                    <div id="guests" class="hb-form-field-input hb_input_field">
                        <input type="text" id="number" class="day" value="01" />
                        <input class="month" type="text" value="Guests" />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <p class="hb-submit">
                <span class="contact-info">Need Help: <span>(+381)xxxxxxxx</span></span>
                <button class="gold_inquiry" type="submit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Send
                    Inquiry</button>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and now fun part that I didnt understand very-well: in theme.js file is some part regarding this section:

```js
$('#guests').each(function () {
    //debugger;
    var $form_list = $('.sc-hb-rooms-search.style-01 .hb-form-field-list');
    $('#guests').on('click touch', function () {
        $form_list.toggleClass('active');
    });
    $(document).on('click touch', function (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).parents().addBack().is('#guests')) {
            $form_list.removeClass('active');
        }
    });
    $form_list.on('click touch', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});

$('.goUp').on('click', function () {
    var index = $('select[name="adults_capacity"] option:selected').index();
    var count = $(' select[name="adults_capacity"] option').length;

    if (index + 1 >= count) {
        return;
    }

    var selected = $($('select[name="adults_capacity"] option')[index + 1]).val();

    $('select[name="adults_capacity"]').val(selected);

});
$('.goDown').on('click', function () {
    var index = $('select[name="adults_capacity"] option:selected').index();
    if (index <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    var selected = $($('select[name="adults_capacity"] option')[index - 1]).val();
    $('select[name="adults_capacity"]').val(selected);
});

function changeNumber() {
    var $max_child = $(' select[name="max_child"] option:selected').html();
    var $adults_capacity = $('select[name="adults_capacity"] option:selected').html();
    var $number_total = Math.round($adults_capacity);
    if ($number_total < 10) {
        $('#number').val('0' + $number_total);
    } else {
        $('#number').val($number_total);
    }
}

$('.sc-hb-rooms-search.style-01 .goUp').on('click', function () {
    changeNumber();
});
$('.sc-hb-rooms-search.style-01 .goDown').on('click', function () {
    changeNumber();
});
```

This JS script is called onLoad of a page, so I dont know how to put some second unique ids and call it right.

I was trying like `$('#guests, #guests1').each(function () {...}` but that didn't do a trick..

I think that the key is `var $form_list = $('.sc-hb-rooms-search.style-01 .hb-form-field-list');` but that no makes sense to me because it is a class selector it should be relevant to both sections right?

I would not bother you with CSS files because I think they are irrelevant in this case.

**Attempt #1**:
I tried to add duplicate code in my js like this:

```
$('#guests').each(function () {
            //debugger;
            var $form_list = $('.sc-hb-rooms-search.style-01 .hb-form-field-list');
            $('#guests').on('click touch', function () {
                $form_list.toggleClass('active');
            });
            $(document).on('click touch', function (event) {
                if (!$(event.target).parents().addBack().is('#guests')) {
                    $form_list.removeClass('active');
                }
            });
            $form_list.on('click touch', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        });

        $('#guests1').each(function () {
            //debugger;
            var $form_list1 = $('.sc-hb-rooms-search.style-01 .hb-form-field-list');
            $('#guests1').on('click touch', function () {
                $form_list1.toggleClass('active');
            });
            $(document).on('click touch', function (event) {
                if (!$(event.target).parents().addBack().is('#guests1')) {
                    $form_list1.removeClass('active');
                }
            });
            $form_list1.on('click touch', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        });
```

and I edited respectively second section for input `id=guests` to `id=guests1`

**Result**: Now either the first or the second popup won't work.
Link to the repo: [repo](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EnKi08SVODzx3nBD160FaluEAf1jESn6)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to why it doesn't work lies in this line:

```
$('#guests').on('click touch', function () {
   $form_list.toggleClass('active');
});
```

here the form_list gets toggled if you click on #guests. But you can't just add `#guests2` here because then you would toggle both divs on each click. 
Currently this function is written in a way that it can only be included in the page once, if you need it multiple times you need to rewrite it.

This is an idea on how to get you started, try replacing all your `$('#guests').each()` function with this block:

```
 <div class="hb-form-field-input hb_input_field MY_TOGGLE_CLASS">
       <input type="text" id="number2" class="day" value="01" />
        <input class="month" type="text" value="Guests" />
 </div>
 <div class="hb-form-field-list MY_SECOND_CUSTOM_CLASS"> ... </div>    


//Multidate
$('.MY_TOGGLE_CLASS').on("click", function() {
    $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
});

$('.MY_SECOND_CUSTOM_CLASS').on('click touch', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on('click touch', function (event) {
  if (!$(event.target).closest('.MY_TOGGLE_CLASS').length) {
     $('.MY_SECOND_CUSTOM_CLASS').removeClass('active');
  }
```

});

Comment: you can see my updated post as Attempt #1 - I just copied whole section, and edited to `guests1` but still doesnt work. thanks

Comment: that's because your `form_list` and `form_list1` variable have the same content. The function needs to be rewritten to not use IDs and to get the toggle-element relative to the clicked element and not a global css selector.

Comment: edited my answer a bit to get you started, this is how you would have to start refactoring this.

Comment: and what would be a my_toggle class? what I need to put into my css? please add complete solution, to accept your answer

Comment: you can chose whatever you want as classname, just make sure it is the same in every block. Also nothing has to be put into your CSS, these classes are just for the JS functions I posted. Since I don't have relevant CSS to test the showing/hiding I don't know if this works 100% but this is the way to go.

Comment: nope, I just tested..still the same, first section is works ok, but second wont open a sub-section..I commented old js lines, and just put it yours..

Comment: and you put `MY_SECOND_CUSTOM_CLASS` into different place then in the first section? are you sure?

Comment: of course the second class needs to be in another place. Then can you please create a working, minimal example where we can see `one` toggle working as it should?

Comment: please see my updated question..I add the repo link to my GDrive..sorry, I've tried jsFiddle, but I didnt manage to get fully working example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198712/discussion-between-stefan0309-and-cloned).

Comment: hello again, I didnt resolve this issue. The strange thing that my value wont update on guests, so if I put 5 guests it renders 5 on the view, but its value is still 1.

Comment: Im looking forward to hear from you! @cloned

Comment: This is now a different problem. It is related to this question but the initial question was to just show the popup. If there are further questions it's better to open a new question with specific info on what your problem is.